# BackgroundColor affect the ripple of Raised Button

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-styles

The following is the custom ripple style of button:

**Button**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        style="@style/btn_start_style"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </Button>
```

**Style: btn_start_style**

If I set "Background" in XML,the "style" will not working,so I set "Background" in "style".

```
 <style name="btn_start_style" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_raised_start</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Background:  btn_raised_start.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/btn_start"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

When click a "Raised Button",I want to change the BackgroundColor.

```
btnStop.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btn_start_day));
```

**But when I change  the BackgroundColor by the above code,the ripple gone!**

Comment: Have you seen this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color

Comment: Yeah, but i want to change the color perennially when click it

Comment: If you want to change the background color so that it never change, then you won't see ripple.. As far as I understand you want to change the ripple color, not the button color, right? You can create a separate selector for your ripple and change that when you do the click. Don't set the background color because it replaces the ripple drawable. Instead, get the ripple object and change the selector on it.

Comment: could you give me a example?

Comment: I think this should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787870/how-to-use-rippledrawable-programmatically-in-code-not-xml-with-android-5-0-lo